# In JMeter, how do I validate a value returned in json against a value calculated from two jmeter variables?

Tags: jmeter

I am extracting $.matching_results from this json:

```
{
  "matching_results": 5,
  "enrichments": {
    "keywords": [
      {
        "text": "shore of Mobile Bay",
        "relevance": 0.809978
      }
    ],
    "concepts": [
      {
        "text": "Mobile, Alabama",
        "relevance": 0.972324
      },
      {
        "text": "Birmingham, Alabama",
        "relevance": 0.954301
      }
    ]
  },
  "session_token": "1_e7R7s9QIt28pN8p3_TzjR8acCX"
}
```

and I want to compare it against the product of two variables
`${__BeanShell(${__evalVar(numAssetThreads)}*${__evalVar(numAssetLoops)})}`

I have tried the expression above and this expression
`${__BeanShell(String.valueOf(${__evalVar(numAssetThreads)}*${__evalVar(numAssetLoops)}))}`

and I have tried it with and without `Match as a regular expression` specified.

I also tried
`${__BeanShell(${__V(numAssetThreads)}*${__V(numAssetLoops)})}`

In all cases, I get an error message similar to this:

```
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Value expected to match regexp '5 ', but it did not match: '5'
```

or

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Value expected to be '2 ', but found '2'
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Value expected to match regexp '5 ', but it did not match: '5'

there is a space after 5  here --^
```

Remove this space somehow and your assertion should start working.

Be aware that since JMeter 3.1 you should consider migrating to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as:

1. Groovy is compatible with modern Java features while Beanshell is stuck at Java 5 syntax
2. Groovy provides ["syntax sugar"](http://www.groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of Java SDK
3. [Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).